# How do I install Hadoop and Pydoop on a fresh Ubuntu instance

Tags: python, ubuntu, hadoop, amazon-web-services

Most of the setup instructions I see are verbose. Is there a near script-like set of commands that we can just execute to set up Hadoop and Pydoop on an Ubuntu instance on Amazon EC2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an Ubuntu instance. I set mine up as an Ubuntu 14.04 Linux on a m3.medium spot instance with 20GB data store (delete on termination) with all ports open (to be on the safe side).

`ssh` into the server and copy-paste the commands below, paragraph by paragraph.

```
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install default-jdk
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ''                            # Press Enter when prompted

cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

# See http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/ for latest file version
wget http://download.nextag.com/apache/hadoop/common/current/hadoop-2.6.0.tar.gz
tar xfz hadoop-2.6.0.tar.gz

# Replace the folder/file names for your system
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.6.0
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

Configure Hadoop

```
# Add these into the Hadoop env
cat >> $HADOOP_PREFIX/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh <<EOF
export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}
export HADOOP_PREFIX=${HADOOP_PREFIX}
EOF

cat > $HADOOP_PREFIX/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml <<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
EOF

cat > $HADOOP_PREFIX/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml <<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
EOF
```

Run a Standalone node and add files to it

```
# Format and start HDFS
$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin/hdfs namenode -format
$HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin/start-dfs.sh

# Create a folder
$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /user
$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/sample

# Copy input files into HDFS
$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin/hdfs dfs -put $HADOOP_PREFIX/etc/hadoop/*.xml /user/sample/

# Run example
$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_PREFIX/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar grep /user/sample /user/output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
```

Install Pydoop

```
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential python-dev
sudo bash    # To avoid sudo pip install not geting the env variables
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.6.0
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
pip install pydoop
```

Test Pydoop with this Python script:

```
import pydoop.hdfs
hdfs = pydoop.hdfs.hdfs()
hdfs.list_directory('/user/sample')
# This lists all files under /user/sample
```

Answer (score 9):

Another solution would be to use Juju (Ubuntu's service orchestration framework).

First install the Juju client on your standard computer:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/stable
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install juju-core
```

(instructions for MacOS and Windows are also available [here](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/getting-started))

Then generate a configuration file

```
juju generate-config
```

And modify it with your preferred cloud credentials (AWS, Azure, GCE...). Based on the naming for m3.medium, I assume you use AWS hence follow [these instructions](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/config-aws)

Note: The above has to be done only once.

Now bootstrap

```
 juju bootstrap amazon
```

Deploy a GUI (optional) like the demo available on the website

```
juju deploy --to 0 juju-gui && juju expose juju-gui
```

You'll find the URL of the GUI and password with:

```
juju api-endpoints | cut -f1 -d":"
cat ~/.juju/environments/amazon.jenv | grep pass
```

Note that the above steps are preliminary to any Juju deployment, and can be re-used everytime you want to spin the environment.

Now comes your use case with Hadoop. You have several options.

1. Just deploy 1 node of Hadoop

   ```
   juju deploy --constraints "cpu-cores=2 mem=4G root-disk=20G" hadoop
   ```

You can track the deployment with

```
juju debug-log
```

and get info about the new instances with

```
juju status
```

This is the only command you'll need to deploy Hadoop (you could consider Juju as an evolution of apt for complex systems)

2. Deploy a cluster of 3 nodes with HDFS and MapReduce

   ```
   juju deploy hadoop hadoop-master
   juju deploy hadoop hadoop-slavecluster
   juju add-unit -n 2 hadoop-slavecluster
   juju add-relation hadoop-master:namenode hadoop-slavecluster:datanode
   juju add-relation hadoop-master:resourcemanager hadoop-slavecluster:nodemanager
   ```
3. Scale out usage (separate HDFS & MapReduce, experimental)

   ```
   juju deploy hadoop hdfs-namenode
   juju deploy hadoop hdfs-datacluster
   juju add-unit -n 2 hdfs-datacluster
   juju add-relation hdfs-namenode:namenode hdfs-datacluster:datanode
   juju deploy hadoop mapred-resourcemanager
   juju deploy hadoop mapred-taskcluster
   juju add-unit -n 2 mapred-taskcluster
   juju add-relation mapred-resourcemanager:mapred-namenode hdfs-namenode:namenode
   juju add-relation mapred-taskcluster:mapred-namenode hdfs-namenode:namenode
   juju add-relation mapred-resourcemanager:resourcemanager mapred-taskcluster:nodemanager
   ```

For Pydoop, you'll have to deploy it manually as in the first answer (you have access to the Juju instances via "juju ssh "), or you can write a "charm" (a method for Juju to learn how to deploy pydoop).

Comment: from your long answer only following seems to address the question: _"you'll have to deploy it manually..."_ and _"you can write ..."_